# Gmaps Js and ASP.net textbox constantly clearing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, hosting

I am developing an asp.net application which will display the current location on a google map when the user clicks a button.
The idea is that when the user clicks on the "my-location" button and the co-ords are displayed in the textbox and the location is displayed on the map.

The problem is that this code works perfectly on my local machine but as soon as i deploy it to HostGator the textbox is filled with the co-ords and a split second later is cleared.

Here is the code

The asp.net button

```
<asp:Button ID="mylocation" runat="server" Text="My Location" OnClientClick="getLocation()" CssClass="my-location-button" title="My Location" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

The javascript

```
 function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var lat;
    var lng;

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;

    //Google Maps
    var map2;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17
    };

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GMap1'),
        mapOptions);

    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);                                            

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map2,
        position: pos,
        content: 'You are here!'
    });

    map2.setCenter(pos);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map2
    });

    infowindow.open(map2, marker);

    //Display the lat and lng in txtbox
    var textBox1 = document.getElementById('fromtext');
    textBox1.value = lat + ", " + lng;


}
```

The google maps declaration is in the site.master as

```
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"> </script>
```

How is it possible that this particular code works on local and on host it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here, since I can't add comments to questions yet. Are you sure that page is not posting back, try returning false from the  `getLocation()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
OnClientClick="getLocation()"
```

to

```
OnClientClick="return getLocation()"
```

and added return false to my functions and it works :)  Thanks for the help